# TypeError: u.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

I am working on a whatsapp clone app using react, firebase
[image]

messages, user name, timestamp are recieved from firestore using this code:

```
<div className="chat__body">
                {messages.map(message => (
                    <p className={`chat__message ${true && "chat__reciever"}`}>
                        <span className="chat__name">{message.name}</span>
                        {message.message}
                        <span className="chat__timestamp">
                            {new Date(message.timestamp?.toDate())
                                .toUTCString()}
                        </span>
                    </p>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="chat__footer">
                <InsertEmoticonIcon />
                <form >
                    <input value={input} onChange={(event) => 
setInput(event.target.value)} placeholder="Type a message" type="text" />
                    <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit">Send </button>
                </form>
                <MicIcon />
            </div>
```

The input field texts are captured in {sendMessage} which are viewed in console as input value.

```
//probably sendMessage onClick event is causing this error.

 const sendMessage = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("You typed ", input);

        db.collection('groups').doc(groupId)
            .collection(messages).add({
                message: input,
                name: user.displayName,
                timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            });
        setInput('');
    }
```

as the firestore is set, the inputs are set as messages, name and timestamps set from google authentication in collection like this:

[image]

When I type on the input field, those inputs are supposed to be showed in chat instead showing error:TypeError: u.split is not a function
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should log what `u` is just prior to using it to understand the issue. The error means that `u` is not a string or an array, where `.split()` can be used.

Comment: Have you checked the error stack? Is any of your project files mentioned? If so, could you included the code (from your project) that is referenced in the error stack? (Preferably adding a comment to signify what line of code is responsible for the error.)

Comment: @3limin4t0r modified and added error stack. probably sendMessage onClick event is causing this error. though this onClick event works on console log

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes i have console logged the input which works fine but doesn't shows on chat. I have modified now

Comment: *i have console logged the input which works fine* <-- What does this mean? What, exactly, do you get when you log `u`?

Comment: u.split are are originated in node_modules files.@ScottMarcus

Comment: @DanCantir groupId is id of each chat which is from App.js used as route for each groupchat like <Route path="/groups/:groupId">. I have used useParam to import in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `messages` as an array, not as a string.

Change your code to

```
db.collection("groups").doc(groupId).collection("messages").add({
  message: input,
  name: user.displayName,
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error stack the first project file seems to be:

> ```
> ...
> at e.collection (...)
> at sendMessage (Chat.js:47)
> ...
> ```

Since you supplied the `sendMessage` definition I will assume that the definition is located in `Chat.js`. You haven't given us any line numbers to work with, however the line above "at sendMessage" tells us what function/method you called in `sendMessage` that caused the error. In your case this was a `collection` call.

Looking at your code:

> ```js
> const sendMessage = (event) => {
>   event.preventDefault();
>   console.log("You typed ", input);
>
>   db.collection('groups').doc(groupId)
>     .collection(messages).add({
>       message: input,
>       name: user.displayName,
>       timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
>     });
>   setInput('');
> }
> ```

You make 2 `collection` calls. `.collection('groups')` and `.collection(messages)`. Assuming that `db` is an `Firestore` instance the first `collection` call has [the following signature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#collection):

> collection ( collectionPath :  *string* ) : [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) < [DocumentData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore#documentdata) >

The second `collection` call is called upon a `DocumentReference` but [has the same signature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection).

Your first `collection` call provides a string `'groups'` as argument which looks fine. Your second `collection` call provides `messages` as the argument, which is probably an array (you call `messages.map` in your first code block). Since the method is expecting a string it throws an error.

Comment: yes you got it right I passed as array not string now its working. Thanks a lot for for your kind and brief explanation.